# Speed of light in a medium in different frames of reference

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, refraction

Relativity states that speed of light in a vacuum is the same regardless of the observer. Does the same hold if the light is travelling through a medium?

Comment: You need to be clearer on what you mean. Relativity says the speed of light is the same in any *reference frame* - it does not refer to "observers", or imply that every object has it's own unique frame in which it is central, stationary, and equivalent to all other frames. Also, what kind of "medium" do you mean? Space itself is the "medium" in relativity. Or do you mean a medium made of some sort of substance, like a glass lens?

Comment: The speed of light in a medium can in principle be anything, so if this were true in general, then it would be true for a speed of, say, 50 miles per hour.    Have you noticed that people sometimes drive past you at this speed?

Comment: Yes I meant a medium made of a physical material. Everywhere I've looked, the statement of relativity only refers to the speed of light in a vacuum; the confusion arose when I saw my textbook saying the speed of light in a non vacuum medium depends of the frame of reference

Comment: @sg6, the speed of light through a non-vacuum medium, is simply some ratio of the vacuum speed in that reference frame. As Mateusz answers below. Note that the vacuum itself, or empty space, also plays the role of a medium in relativity.

Comment: So the textbook must be wrong then. Thanks a lot, good sir!

Comment: @sg6, what exactly did your textbook say? Perhaps edit your question to include a reference and a quote from it.

Comment: It simply listed some factors(one of which was the observer's speed) and asked which of those the speed of light in vacuum depended, and likewise for the speed in some other physical medium. It's a high school level book, so tbh I wouldn't trust it too much.

Comment: There is a difference between the phase velocity and the group velocity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the light velocity in a medium resting in an inertial system $S$ is $u \lt c$. Then, to obtain the light velocity seen from an observer in a different inertial system $S'$ with relative velocity $v$, you have to use the [velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) of Special Relativity $$u'=\frac {u+v}{1+u'v/c^2}$$ This shows that the velocity of light in a medium is not independent of the observer. It changes according to the SR velocity addition formula.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no". Although Maxwell's equations and light-based Gedanken experiments had a lot to do with relativity's inception--the significance of $c$ is that it describes how time and space scale in Minkowski space (M4)--so it's really a parameter describing the shape of spacetime--and in fact everything moves through M4 with $u_{\mu}u^{\mu} = c^2 $, which means if you have a 3 velocity of $c$ in one frame--you have that in all frames--and the speed of light in a vacuum is $c$.

For a photon in a medium, it would appear as a particle with four velocity:

$$ u_{\mu} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}}(1, \frac 1 n \hat{\bf x}) $$

and transform accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm. I think the interesting question might be how you compose the coordinate speed of the light front in the medium $v_\gamma$ and the coordinate speed of the medium $v_m$ such that you can recover $c/n$ which should be the speed of the light front in the medium's rest-frame. Must think a bit about that. Though actually I think I would work the problem the other way 'round.

Comment: @dmckee - You a right! See my answer below which corresponds to your reasoning.

Comment: @dmckee After _needing_ stellar aberrations, I did away with wavefronts and stuck with $k_{\mu} = (\omega/c, {\bf k})$ and transforming via $\Lambda$--(it impressed the engineers to no end). Regarding boosting the medium, I don't think $n$ is a scalar--since (in gases at least) it's electron density, which undergoes Lorentz contraction.

Comment: *"I don't think $n$ is a scalar"* ::stonkered gape:: I fear that you're right about that. And it make the problem nasty.

Answer (score -1):

Speed of light in medium are defined by:

$$  v = \frac{c}{n},   $$

where $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum and $ n $ is refractive index of medium.

Comment: The refractive index gives you only the phase velocity in the medium not the  group velocity which is, in general, different to the phase velocity. Also, in my opinion, you did not answer the question whether in a medium that is not vacuum the speed of light is the same for different observers.